# creating more randomness in texture image

Tags: texturing

Lack of better wording so im creating like a red clay roof that i made by creating a root object to apply to a particle system. Now i applied a texture image to the root object which in turn applied to the rest of the shingles. The issue i dont know how to get passed is how can i work it so i can create randomness within the texture so that every shingle doesnt look exactly the same?

[image: clay texture]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*In general for image texture randomness you need to offset texture in X, Y axis for each object. For that you will need also seamless texture to prevent edge texture appearance.*

### Random Location

One way to randomise location can be done with *Object Info* node > **Random** plugged into *Mapping node* > *Location*

[image]

### Random Color

similar way you can be randomise a color of tiles

[image]

### Random Rotation

... you can randomise rotation as well, but directly connected *Random* to Rot cause "shearing", because texture would be rotated in all axis. To prevent this result use **Separate XYZ** node and **Combine XYZ** and connect only Z axis. To rotate more or less you can add between *Math* node and increase or decrease value.)

[image]

[image]